# Plots with functions like n/2

Tags: pgfplots, plot, tikz-pic

i'm using tikzpicture and pgfplots to make my plots and i'm currently facing a problem when i use a function like 2/x

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ ymin=-10, ymax=10, xmin=-10, xmax=10, axis lines=middle, xlabel = $x$ , ylabel = $y$]
        \addplot[dashed, color=red]{ (2)/(x) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

It gives me multiple errors like: dimension too large and arithmetic overflow, anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: you must restrict the domain to avoid that you divide by zero (or nearly zero). See section 4.22 Skipping Or Changing Coordinates in the pgfplots documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'jump' over the singularity in x=0 whit 2 domains:

```
\addplot[dashed, color=red,domain =-10:-.1]{ (2)/(x) };
\addplot[dashed, color=red,domain =0.1:10]{ (2)/(x) };
```

So the output is:

[image]